# Python: Print iterates too many times

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures

There is one thing I don't really understand with Python. When I create an array, append data to it and try to print, the iterations repeats itself too many time, for example:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as fh1:
    array = []
        counter = 0
        for line in fh1:
            line = line.rstrip("\n")
            counter +=1
            array.append((line, counter))
            for line, counter in (array):
                print line, ":", counter
```

file.txt:

```
 a
 b
...
 y
 z
```

Script output is for some reason duplicating several times. I get this problem with every array I build and try to print. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: `for line, counter in (array):`: `array` contains all lines up so far. For every new line you are printing every previous line. Did you want too loop over the array outside of the reader loop, instead?

Comment: Oh my God... I totally forgot about this specific thing with Python. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gets printed multiple times due to the fact that `for line, counter in (array):` is with in another for loop

Actually it would be printed for each line in the file since the for loop iterates over the lines of the file

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as fh1:
    array = []
    counter = 0
    for line in fh1:
        line = line.rstrip("\n")
        counter +=1
        array.append((line, counter))
for line, counter in (array):
    print line, ":", counter
```

Comment: or: Mind the indentation

Comment: @WorldSEnder yeah without indentation python is nothing :p

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot about spacing in Python.

Comment: @MagomedSegaIsmailov do keep that in mind :) if this answered your question can you accept it

Comment: @VigneshKalai Yes sir!

Comment: @MagomedSegaIsmailov sir! :P